# Specific HTML code generator using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, code-generation

I made a website, but now I came with an idea to make a code generator. You have to insert text in text boxes and it will generate code.

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
    $("#result").text(
        '<div width="' + $("#width").val() + 
        'px" height="' + $("#height").val() + 
        'px">' + $("#content").val() + 
        '</div>');
});
```

I found this solution on http://jsfiddle.net/NzFeb/ but it doesn't work somehow with my code.

You can see what I did (CSS and Markup) at http://go.filiparag.com/mnmuis-generator but now I need Jquery code.

What I have done with Jquery (it doesn't work):

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
 $("#code").text(

        '<!--POST-->
        <div id="post"> <div id="' + $("#tag").val() + '" class="tag_post"></div>
            <a href="' + $("#image-link").val() + '" data-lightbox="' + $("#title").val() + '" title="' + $("#title").val() + '">
            <img src="' + $("#image-link").val() + '" width="'IMAGE_WIDTH'" height="'IMAGE_HEIGHT'" id="post-image-right"/> </a>
            <text id="post-title">' + $("#title").val() + '</text> <br>
            <text id="post-short-story">' + $("#short-story").val() + '</text> <br> <br>
            <text id="post-text">

            ' + $("#story").val() + '

            </text>
        </div>
        <!--POST END-->'

        );
    });
```

These id's are from `<input type="text">` and `<textarea>`.

Comment: `text()` is just text not html codes

Comment: if you want html codes, use `html()`

Comment: @JayHarris Can you give me link of a jsfiddle or example?

Comment: You really dont need an example - text() gets or sets text, html() gets or sets html

Comment: You should jsfiddle your own code in the first place

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QAraV/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your problem correctly, this is the desired code or result http://jsfiddle.net/NzFeb/
if so then your problem is here

```
' width="'IMAGE_WIDTH'" height="'IMAGE_HEIGHT'"'
 // is IMAGE_WIDTH a variable or part of the string

 // if its a variable use the plus sign
 ' width="' + IMAGE_WIDTH + '" height="' + IMAGE_HEIGHT + '"'

 // if its part of the string remove the single qoute
 ' width="IMAGE_WIDTH" height="IMAGE_HEIGHT"'
```

if the fiddle i pointed to is not the desired code then, change text() to  html()

```
$("#code").html(
```

side note: `<text>` is not a valid html tag

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but again when I corrected the code it worked like I didn't (same problem).

Comment: in your recent fiddle: 1) you didn't include jQuery 2) you have a multi line errors, use \ to escape a multi line string or on the safe side close each line with a string and plus sign. here this works http://jsfiddle.net/QAraV/2/

Comment: THANKS A LOT for the fix, but mysteriously  code doesn't work on my page but in fiddle it does :( I don't blame you, it's probably my fault because I am still newbie to programming.

Comment: I suggest you go back to the basic's, and learn javascript/jQuery from the beginning so you can better solve common problems associated with the program languages